# Observable java object doesnt update

Tags: java, android, observable

this is my ActivityA:

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity implement Observer
{

    private Mouse _mouse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ...

        _mouse = new Mouse();
        _mouse.posX = 30;
        _mouse.addObserver(this);


    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
        intent.putExtra("Mouse", Parcels.wrap(mouse));
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg)
    {
        // Never get called.
        Log.e("TAG", "We're updating the object");
    }
}
```

And this is my ActivityB:

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    private Mouse _mouse;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ...

        _mouse = Parcels.unwrap(getIntent().getParcelableExtra("Mouse"));

        Log.v("AB", "X: "_mouse.posX); // This is 30
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        _mouse.posX = 100;
        _mouse.NotifyObservers();

    }
}
```

Finally my model looks like this:

```
public class Mouse extends Observable
{
    public int posX;

    public void NotifyObservers()
    {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }
}
```

I can't get it working because "update" in ActivityA is never called. Maybe I forgot something? Is there any better way of notify when a object is updated from other activity without using activity result code?

Comment: You failed to name your method correctly. `NotifyObservers()` must start with a lower case letter (as every method name should in Java). Then also you have to modify the call inside the method to `super.notifyObservers();` Otherwise you create an endless loop for which you may need a bigger maschine to execute successfully... ;o)

Comment: The method is fine, is not overrided.

Answer (score 1):

- First thing you need to register your observer to getting update called by doing  `_mouse.addObserver(this);` just after `_mouse = new Mouse();`
- Second thing you've made you `Mouse` model `parcelable` using `Parcels wrap and unwrap`. and even you have you have used `serializable` it doesn't work.

Because you have registered your listener in `Obervable` extended by `Mouse` class which has list of obeservers is not parcelable or serializable.

So whenever you're passing your model to `ActivityB`, old listener of `ActivityA` is removed.

To check my answer do first step which I have indicated and call `_mouse.NotifyObservers();` from `ActivityA` itself.

you'll get callback on `update`.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle you're getting it wrong. #Dex had made own notifyObservers() which don't need any super method call.

Comment: If you cannot understand the answer never give your feedback on it or don't mark down.

Comment: Hello there, the problem is that I need to pass my model from activityA to activityB.. I already added .addObserver but still doesnt work.

Comment: There are 3 options to do that is 1) event bus ,2) singleInstance and 3) accessing model statically from activityB.  because you cann't achieve your requeirent by passing object from activity A to B using intent.

Comment: Also, If activity is not mandatory, then use fragment and then pass model in argument which will work as it will not create another model on next fragmentB so it can listen in fragment A.